# Is there any utility to run multiple spring batch jobs programmatically ?

Tags: spring-batch

Am invoking spring jobs based on event, however i hv couple jobs to execute on specific event which could execute in parallel, Is there any utility class which can execute multiple jobs in parallel? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We don't offer anything specific for launching multiple jobs based on a single message out of the box with Spring Batch.  However, writing a message handler that can handle that scenario should be pretty trivial.